# Update table if certain fields are null with related values from a different column

Tags: mysql, kettle

I am writing an ETL in kettle pentaho to create a table from various sources including google analytics.

so **Table 1** = All data from website joined to google analytics information
   **Table 2** = All Duplicate data from Table 1 joined to google analytics information

my problem is that some info on table 1 has the google analytics information missing but table 2 shows some data for Google Analytics on the same reference_number

So what I want to do is lookup [reference_number] from table 1 to table 2 and populate table 1 where some columns are null from info on table 2

Quick example EDIT*

```
Table 1 (Main Table) * *This table has an index built in on website_reference number (Unique)*
  website_Reference_number   GA_info_1   GA_info_2 
  A1              null       null
  A2               x           y

Table 2 (Duplicates from Table 1)           
  eventlabel   GA_info_1   GA_info_2
  A1               z            z
  A2               x            y
```

my **output** should be the following

```
Table 1 (Main Table)
Ref_number   GA_info_1   GA_info_2 
A1               z            z
A2               x            y
```

I am using a My_SQL database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable
LEFT JOIN table2 ON mytable.Ref_number = table2.Ref_number
SET mytable.GA_info_1 = COALESCE (
    mytable.GA_info_1,
    table2.GA_info_1
),
 mytable.GA_info_2 = COALESCE (
    mytable.GA_info_2,
    table2.GA_info_2
)
WHERE
    mytable.GA_info_1 IS NULL
OR mytable.GA_info_2 IS NULL
```

Put all the fields which might be null into the where clause.

If the field is not null it will not be updated because it is the first argument in the `coalesce` function, if it is null it will be updated by the field of the other table.

**edit**: Also you can try it like this:

```
UPDATE mytable
INNER JOIN table2 ON mytable.Ref_number = table2.Ref_number
SET mytable.GA_info_1 = COALESCE (
    mytable.GA_info_1,
    table2.GA_info_1
),
 mytable.GA_info_2 = COALESCE (
    mytable.GA_info_2,
    table2.GA_info_2
)
WHERE
    CONCAT(mytable.GA_info_1, mytable.GA_info_2) IS NULL
```

**For the performance issue**: (as already mentioned in the comments)

Since you are not using the primary or foreign keys to join the tables, you would have to set an index on your Ref_number columns to speed up the join.

Comment: Hey Philipp. This runs very slowly. Is there a way I can improve the runtime on this query. My code as follows

Comment: Is `ID` your primary key on the table? I misread your post, you have to change the join so it uses `Ref_number`, you could then set a index on that one. The where might be faster if you use `WHERE CONCAT(mytable.GA_info_1, mytable.GA_info_2) IS NULL`

Comment: Unfortunitely not. These are duplicates so the id join wont work, i had to write java to clean the data and now the link from table 1 is website_reference_number on event label from 2

Comment: Can you update the structure of your tables in your question? We need to talk about the same columns, there is no website_reference_number in your sample

Comment: these columns i am joining on are the ref numbers.its just different names for them on different tables. GA uses eventlabel and Enquiries uses website_reference_number

Comment: Ok, if you can translate 'my' columnnames to yours it will be fine. Can you set an index on the join columns?

Comment: Oh yes and for some reason the actual code i am using (answer below) duplicates the data. It brings in a new entry of old data everytime i run

Comment: Yes I can probably do that

Comment: Ok set an index on your fields, that will speed up the join. Using `concat()` in the where 'might' speed up the where, not sure on that one though

Comment: Thanks so much> Appreciated

Comment: glad if it helped :) Can you edit your question and add the code from your answer to it, so it stays consistent and contains all the information there is. Also pls accept my answer if it helped, you can change it later again if someone else has a better solution to your problem.

Comment: Quick question for the join part.

Comment: UPDATE mytable
LEFT JOIN mytable AS table2 ON mytable.Ref_number = table2.Ref_number
SET mytable.GA_info_1 = COALESCE (
    mytable.GA_info_1,
    table2.GA_info_1

Comment: looks like you want to join [my table] with [table 2] but you call my table as table 2 so you are updating a table by itself. Im puzzled. What am i missing out on

Comment: In my results you can find the updated data below and not actually joined.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Seems I used the wrong table for the join

Answer (score 0):

```
    UPDATE DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST
LEFT JOIN DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST AS STAGING_GA ON DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.website_reference_number = STAGING_GA.eventlabel
SET DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.eventlabel = COALESCE (
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.eventlabel,
STAGING_GA.eventlabel
),
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.sourcemedium = COALESCE (
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.sourcemedium,
STAGING_GA.sourcemedium
)
,
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.deviceCategory = COALESCE (
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.deviceCategory,
STAGING_GA.deviceCategory
)
,
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.avgSessionDuration = COALESCE (
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.avgSessionDuration,
STAGING_GA.avgSessionDuration
)
,
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.timeonpage = COALESCE (
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.timeonpage,
STAGING_GA.timeonpage
)
,
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.avgtimeonpage = COALESCE (
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.avgtimeonpage,
STAGING_GA.avgtimeonpage
)
,
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.bouncerate = COALESCE (
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.bouncerate,
STAGING_GA.bouncerate
)
,
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.profileid = COALESCE (
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.profileid,
STAGING_GA.profileid
)
,
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.webpropertyid = COALESCE (
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.webpropertyid,
STAGING_GA.webpropertyid
)
,
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.accountname = COALESCE (
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.accountname,
STAGING_GA.accountname
)
,
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.tableid = COALESCE (
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.tableid,
STAGING_GA.tableid
)
,
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.tablename = COALESCE (
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.tablename,
STAGING_GA.tablename
)
,
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.keyword = COALESCE (
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.keyword,
STAGING_GA.keyword
)
,
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.country = COALESCE (
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.country,
STAGING_GA.country
)
,
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.campaign = COALESCE (
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.campaign,
STAGING_GA.campaign
)
,
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.sessions = COALESCE (
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.sessions,
STAGING_GA.sessions
)
,
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.sessionduration = COALESCE (
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.sessionduration,
STAGING_GA.sessionduration
)
,
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.bounces = COALESCE (
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.bounces,
STAGING_GA.bounces
)
WHERE
DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.EventLabel IS NULL
OR DIM_ENQUIRIES_TEST.SourceMedium IS NULL
;
```

--*I just check one because if one of them is null, it is likely that the rest of the columns that needs to be changed would also be null*

Comment: If one of the checks is null, it is likely that all of them would be null